# Mule 4 : When Autodiscovery automatically applies a policy for a deployed API and manages it, why to add client id enforcement in API specification?

Tags: mule4

I have a question regarding Autodiscovery, and adding code fragments of policies to an API specification.

Using Autodiscovery, we can apply policies and it will be applicable to the deployed application. For example Rate limiting policy applied through Autodiscovery will work fine to manage the access of our API.

Then what is the purpose of adding Client id enforcement or adding the code snippet of this policy to the API RAML? Does this mean that once the RAML changes are done, we again need to update out code to include this new RAMl from exchange and redeploy our application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the snippet is to document that client_id and client_secret have to be send as part of the HTTP request to the REST API. It will also make APIKit validate that it is receiving the expected information for the policy to work.

Comment: So what should be the chronological steps: Create an API in exchange, adding aurodiscovery, adding policies, designing ramp for main ApI, getting ramp snippet for an applied policy, update raml spec, then use this raml for App development in mule, and then deploy by adding appid in mule app using runtime manager. Is my understanding correct?